# Any idea what would cause intermittent 500 serialization error on c#/.net/EF/MVC5 site?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got an Azure web app .NET(4.6.1)/c#/MVC5/EF/Newtonsoft.JSON(6.0.4) that will run fine for a week, and then out of the blue, through 500 errors, and become unusable for everyone.  Restarting and/or Recycling the site brings the site back to life.  I'm struggling to find the root cause.  I've seen some threads out there that suggest that untimely recycling of the app pool can cause this behavior.  Within IIS, however, the site is configured to not ever recycle (idle timeout=0, and recycle schedule set to 0).  Has anyone experienced this or have suggestions?

Below is the verbiage of the error:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'IsCompleted' on 'Weaver.TruckScaleMgmt.Common.Models.TruckLoad'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","StackTrace":" at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":" at Weaver.TruckScaleMgmt.Common.Models.TruckLoad.<>c.b__71_0(TruckLoadQuality t) in C:\Users\wh741\Source\Repos\Scalehouse\Weaver.TruckScaleMgmt.Common\Models\TruckLoad.cs:line 223\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n at Weaver.TruckScaleMgmt.Common.Models.TruckLoad.UpdateCompletedRequirements() in C:\Users\wh741\Source\Repos\Scalehouse\Weaver.TruckScaleMgmt.Common\Models\TruckLoad.cs:line 223\r\n at Weaver.TruckScaleMgmt.Common.Models.TruckLoad.get_IsCompleted() in C:\Users\wh741\Source\Repos\Scalehouse\Weaver.TruckScaleMgmt.Common\Models\TruckLoad.cs:line 335\r\n at GetIsCompleted(Object )\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)"}}}

.
.
.

Update:

I've been able to reproduce the problem, and believe it to be an issue with the serialization of a Boolean variable.  I don't have it fixed yet, but I believe I know the root cause.  The code I posted earlier was not related to the root cause....

Update2:

OK.  I've fixed the problem.  A case that happens once in a blue moon left a null value within a field that was within a linq query.  What I don't know, however, is why this would make the app unusable for everyone.  One instance makes the app wig out for everyone.....

Comment: So what happens in `IsCompleted` and `UpdateCompletedRequirements()`? You've got an NRE there.

Comment: It fails on the quality.where statement below.  I think this is a symptom, however.  It works fine 99% of the time.

Comment: what type of output you are expecting from the controller method? It seems the output is not serialized to json. That is the error

Comment: So next question is: what is `Quality` and where *exactly* do you get the NRE? Apparently you expect `QualityField` always to be not null? Please try to anticipate obvious questions otherwise this is going to be a long day.

Comment: Sorry.....new to this.  I added the definition and population.     QualityField should not be null.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem. A case that happens once in a blue moon left a null value within a field that was within a linq query. What I don't know, however, is why this would make the app unusable for everyone. One instance makes the app wig out for everyone.....